# Первая серия чисел всегда самая большая

Tags: c#

Пробую решить задачу:

> найдите наибольшее количество идущих подряд цифр

Не могу понять в чем ошибка моего кода, вечно выдаёт что первая серия чисел самая большая. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка!

```
string s = "kabab23hzjz782134218jss8";
string num = "123456789";
int max = 0, count = 0;
 
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0;j < num.Length; j++)
  {
     if (s[i] == num[j])
     {
        count++;
     
        if (count > max)
            max = count;
     }
     else
     {
      count = 0;
     }
  }
}
 
Console.WriteLine(max);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Вам не нужно итерировать свою строку с цифрами. Используйте Char.IsDigit

Answer (score 3):

Ваша ошибка в том, как вы проверяете является ли текущий char цифрой. Используйте готовый метод [Char.IsDigit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public int MaxDigitLength(string source)
{
    int result = 0;
    int resultMax = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if(Char.IsDigit(source[i]))
        {
            result++;
            if(result > resultMax)
            {
                resultMax = result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    return resultMax;
}
```

Если по условию вам нельзя использовать готовый метод IsDigit -- напишите свой, отдельно:

```
public bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}
```

Ваша же методика (если вы очень хотите сделать именно так) должна быть такой:

```
public bool IsDigit(char c)
{
    string nums = "0123456789";
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] == c)
            return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Но из-за того, что вы не разделили на отдельные методы у вас произошло некорректное слияние обхода строки s и обхода num. Очень хорошо оберегает от подобных ошибок соблюдение принципа единственной ответственности (SRP) из SOLID.

Вот как должен был выглядеть итоговый алгоритм для вашего варианта:

```
string s = "kabab23hzjz782134218jss8";
string num = "0123456789";
int max = 0, count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    bool isDigit = false;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < num.Length; j++)
    {
        if (s[i] == num[j])
        {
            isDigit = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isDigit)
    {
        count++;

        if (count > max)
            max = count;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(max);
```

PS В принципе, проверка `return c >= '0' && c <= '9'` не даёт прям резкого буста по скорости по сравнению с `string nums = "0123456789";`, несмотря на наличие вложенного for общая сложность так и остаётся O(N), потому что строка nums не растёт с ростом строки s, но просто такая запись более короткая и понятная.

Comment: Последний вариант не работает . Мне нужно не считать сами цифры а считать серии цифр и выбрать самую большую серию :)

Comment: @Zaks Возможно, в мелочах где-то ошибся, но само общее направление показано верно: включите и свои мозги, а не слепо копируйте "дайте мне полностью готовый ответ, чтобы осталось только запустить".